# React: how to select all checkboxes of columns/rows in children component by clicking on parent div

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a `React` components to generate a filter panel.

This is how the part of it looks like:

[image]

What I want to achieve is:

1. When user click on "USAGE" then all checkboxes will be selected/unselected (it depends on which options there are more)
2. When user click on subtype header (receiver/sender) then all checkboxes in one column will be selected/unselected
3. When user click on the label then checkboxes in one row will be selected/unselected

Now time for my code, 1st is header div (in screenshot it is "USAGE" label):

```
render(): React.ReactNode {

    return (
        <div className={'col-xs-12 m-b-xs filter-header'}>
            <div className={'inline'} onClick={this.props.options.toggle}>
                {this.title}
                {this.prepareMissingSystemInformation()}
            </div>
            {this.collapseLink}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then options are above:

```
export interface QuickFilterOptionsProps {
options: any;
isCollapsed: boolean;
}

export class QuickFilterOptions extends React.PureComponent <QuickFilterOptionsProps, {}> {

updateQuickFilters() {
    //method to update filters after changing checkboxes
}

render(): React.ReactNode {
    const newProps = {
        ...this.props,
        updateFilters: this.updateQuickFilters
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div className={'col-xs-12'} id={'QuickFilterComponent' + this.props.options.filter.label}
                 style={{display: this.props.isCollapsed ? 'none' : 'block'}}>
                <table>
                    <OptionValues {...newProps}/>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
}
```

And option values with checkboxes:

```
const GenerateValue = (props: any) => {
// For each subtype
const array = Object.values(props.options.filter.options).slice(0, 10).map((option, index) => {
    const label = option['id'] === '' ? FilterPrettyPrinter.getTranslationForEmptyValue(props.options.filter.property) : option['id'];

    const optionLabel = (
        <td className={'clickable option-label'} onClick={props.options.toggle}
            onMouseEnter={props.options.hoverIn}
            onMouseLeave={props.options.hoverOut}>{label}</td>);

    const checkboxes = props.options.filter.subtypes.map((subtype) => {
        // Checkbox is disabled when it relates to a property that has no connections or calls
        const disabled = option['properties'][subtype.property] === undefined; // || option.properties[subtype.property].calls === 0;
        // Checkbox is selected when it is disabled or has a selected property set to true
        const [selected, setSelected] = useState(disabled || option['properties'][subtype.property].selected);

        const classNames: string[] = ['ff-checkbox-square'];
        // Check if needed
        if (selected) {
            classNames.push('selected');
        }

        const optionValue = () => {
            if (selected) {
                option['properties'][subtype.property].selected = true;
                props.updateFilters();
                props.options.onCheckboxClick();
            } else {
                option['properties'][subtype.property].selected = false;
                props.updateFilters();
                props.options.onCheckboxClick();
            }
        };

        const toggleCheckbox = () => {
            setSelected(!selected);
        }

        // TOOLTIP
        return (
            <td key={UUID.UUID()}>
                <div className={'ff-checkbox>'}>
                    <div
                        className={'ff-checkbox-square ' + (selected ? 'checked ' : '') + (disabled ? 'disabled ' : '')}>
                        <input type='checkbox'
                               className={classNames.join(' ')}
                               defaultChecked={selected}
                               disabled={disabled}
                               onClick={() => toggleCheckbox()}
                               onChange={() => optionValue()}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        );
    });

    return (
        <tr key={UUID.UUID()}>
            {checkboxes}
            {optionLabel}
        </tr>);
});

return <>
    {array}
</>;
};


export function OptionValues(props) {
const isShowMoreButton = Object.keys(props.options.filter.options).length - props.options.maxFilterOptions > 0;


return (
    <>
        {props.options.filter.subtypes.length > 1 ? OptionSubtypeHeader(props.options) : null}
        <tbody>
        <GenerateValue {...props}/>
        </tbody>
        {isShowMoreButton ? QuickFilterFooter(props.options) : null}
    </>);
```

Can someone help me with this?